# Parameter 'props' implicitly has an 'any' type - vuejs error in Typesript

Tags: typescript, vue.js

I'm using `vue 2.6` and `typescript 3.8.3`. I get the error when I add a validator on a prop.

> TS7006: Parameter 'props' implicitly has an 'any' type.

Here is my vue `SFC` component:

```html
<template>
  <h1>{{propF}}</h1>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import { defineComponent } from '@vue/composition-api'
export default defineComponent({
  props:{
    propF: {
      type: String,
      default: 'project',
      validator: (value) => {
        return ['project', 'global'].indexOf(value) !== -1
      }
    }
  },
  setup(props) {

    return {
      props
    }
  }
})
</script>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error about `props` being `any` is actually caused by the `validator`'s untyped `value` argument (which is `unknown`). Specifying the `value`'s type as `string` to match the `propF` type constructor (`String`) resolves the issue:

```js
                     
validator: (value: string) => {/*...*/}
```